# C# Unity Text array to string to show in GameScene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a text array that calculates a `sum: y = ax + b` and now I want it to put the results of Y in a table, but I would have no idea how it should be. If I put a `Debug.Log` in, it sums correctly. I have no idea how to put the values of an array in a string so that it shows the values in a table in the game scene.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Line : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lijn;
    public InputField A;
    public InputField B;
    public float valueA;
    public float valueB;
    public int somX;
    public double somY;
    private int num = 0;
    public Text[] xTabel;
    public Text[] ytabel;
    public Vector3 lijnposition;

    void Update()
    {
        lijn.startWidth = 0.2F;
        lijn.endWidth = 0.2F;

        for(int i = -2; i < 4; i++)
        {
            somY = valueA *(somX * i) + valueB;
            //xTabel[num] = somX.ToString();
            //ytabel[num] = somY.ToString();
            lijn.SetPosition(i, lijnposition);
            Debug.Log(somY);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question you want answered. Are you asking how to save results into a string array? Are you asking how to display this information in the scene?

Comment: its fixed now ty

Comment: Don't you rather have an array of `Text` and want to assign single string values from within the loop? I'm your code I don't see an array of strings ... What was wrong with `ytabel[num] = somY.ToString();` except that `num` is nowhere defined? (You probably would use `var num = i + 2;`)

Comment: That was indeed the problem derHugo! Thanks! :)